# Running a wayland compositor inside Docker

Tags: docker, wayland, container

I am looking for a way to run a Wayland compositor (like Hyprland) inside a docker container. I know I can run it inside Distrobox, but I don't want to run the whole system inside of the container, only the compositor. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: *"the whole system"* : Could you please tell precisely what you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run hyprland inside an archlinux container in debian by just installing seatd in debian and enabling it. The problem I am facing now is alot of programs like vscode and waybar refuse to launch and I don't know why.